# How to decouple a Component from it's own data fetching needs

Tags: reactjs, redux, flux

When a component requires a certain set of data to be fetched before rendering, I usually do something along those lines:

```
class Comp extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.requestData() // triggeres in action in the wrapper
  }
  render() {
    const { data } = this.props.
    return (
       <div>
         {/* do something with data */}
       </div>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Comp)
```

Now I have two React SPA's in which I want to use this component. In one App the needed data needs to be fetched before the component is mounted, in another the data already exists. 
So I was wondering, if there is any best practice regarding the issue of fetching data that is a prerequisite for a component.
Is there a way for the wrapper to listen to `Comp`'s lifecycle? Should I just rename  `requestData` to `onComponentWillMount` and listen to that for action triggering?

Ideally the component should have no concern about if or when to fetch.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly? You could wrap the data request in a conditional. `if (!this.props.data) { this.props.requestData() }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a HoC (Higher order Component) to wrap your vanilla `Comp` component and fetches the data on `onComponentWillMount` (and on `onComponentWillReceiveProps`). As you are using redux I imagine that your `requestData()` callback is creating a redux action that dispatches the data to the global store. Alternatively, if the data is local to this component you could keep it in the state of the HoC.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the requestData action creator call to the React Router event "onEnter", in your routes definition. In this way the component is decoupled from the fetch action creator.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer has been downvoted. It seems a reasonable solution.

Comment: @Manolo Santos If I understand this correctly, if requires React-Router, and also forces you to pass down the props all the way down from the routes.

Comment: Well, if you have a React SPA with more than 1 view, then you have React-Router, otherwise I think you wouldn't use Redux either. You should NOT pass down all the props, as the router "onEnter" event calls the Redux action creator, so the "glue" is the Redux store. The components just get their data from the Redux store by way of the connect (mapStateToProps).